# Recycler View items not showing

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView on my homepage when getting some data from Firebase Realtime Database and then create views with this data, but when I run my app I get some error messages on the log cat and the items on my homepage are not displayed. I have tried everything but nothing is working.

**Also i get this on the log:**

```
D/GGGGGGG: value is (name of user 1)
D/GGGGGGG: value is (name of user 2)
```

**post_item.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:padding="15dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    app:cardElevation="20dp"
    android:outlineSpotShadowColor="@color/teal_200">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/post_username"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:text="By george sepetadelis"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/post_image"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/post_image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/post_username"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/m1" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

**PostModel.java:**

```
package com.sm.socialmeme;

public class PostModel {
    String name;
    String imgUrl;

    // constractors \\
    public PostModel(String name, String imgUrl) {
        this.name = name;
        this.imgUrl = imgUrl;
    }

    public PostModel(){

    }

    // getters and setters \\
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getImgUrl() {
        return imgUrl;
    }

    public void setImgUrl(String imgUrl) {
        this.imgUrl = imgUrl;
    }
}
```

**My database:**
[image: `![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLvIn.jpg)]

**Errors on the log cat:**

```
2021-01-10 18:43:39.976 28203-28203/? E/m.sm.socialmem: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x28000
2021-01-10 18:43:47.168 28203-28706/com.sm.socialmeme E/Perf: Fail to get file list com.sm.socialmeme
2021-01-10 18:43:47.171 28203-28706/com.sm.socialmeme E/Perf: getFolderSize() : Exception_1 = java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
2021-01-10 18:43:51.508 28203-28203/com.sm.socialmeme E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
```

**RecyclerAdapter.java:**

```
package com.sm.socialmeme;

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;

import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;

import java.util.List;

public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder>{

    List<PostModel> postList;
    Context context;

    public RecyclerAdapter(Context context,List<PostModel> postList) {
        this.postList = postList;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @NotNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull @NotNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.post_item,parent,false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull @NotNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        //PostModel postModel = postList.get(position);
        // set username \\
        holder.username.setText(postList.get(position).getName());
        // set image URL \\
        Glide.with(context).load(postList.get(position).getImgUrl()).into(holder.postImg);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return postList.size();
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView username;
        ImageView postImg;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull @NotNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            username = itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_username);
            postImg = itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_image);
        }
    }
}
```

**HomeActivity.java:**

```
package com.sm.socialmeme;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.MimeTypeMap;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask;

import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // global variables \\
    DatabaseReference mRef;
    List<PostModel> postList;
    RecyclerView.Adapter recyclerAdapter;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    ProgressBar progressBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        final FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        final FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        final ImageButton new_post = findViewById(R.id.new_post_btn);
        final ImageButton settings = findViewById(R.id.settingsButton);
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        mRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("posts");
        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar4);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        postList = new ArrayList<>();
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        if (user == null) {
            finish();
            startActivity(new Intent(HomeActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
        }

            mRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener(){
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
                    clearList();
                    for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                        PostModel post = new PostModel();
                        post.setImgUrl(snapshot.child("imgUrl").getValue().toString());
                        post.setName(snapshot.child("name").getValue().toString());
                        postList.add(post);

                        // debug code \\
                        // note: the data from the db is coming correct
                        String value = snapshot.child("imgUrl").getValue().toString();
                        Log.d("GGGGGGGGG","Value is: " + value);
                    }
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError){
                    Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "Error: " + databaseError, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            });

            recyclerAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(HomeActivity.this,postList);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);
            recyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


        settings.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(HomeActivity.this, SettingsActivity.class));
            }
        });

        new_post.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(HomeActivity.this, UploadPhotoActivity.class));
            }
        });
    }

    public void clearList(){
        if (postList != null){
            postList.clear();
            if (recyclerAdapter != null){
                recyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
        postList = new ArrayList<>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show screenshot from the database hierarchy?  you have "users -> posts ->" and then?

Comment: Firebase listener runs on different thread. So use a interface for checking when data retrieving is finished. Then set adapter. Otherwise list will be empty and no data will be shown.

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot.

Comment: @Alex Mamo I add a photo of my database on my post, please help me if you see where is the problem

Comment: So you want to display in the RecyclerView the photos that exist at those URLs?

Comment: @Alex Mamo yes, exactly

Comment: You are also using a `PostModel` class. Please add the content of the class.

Comment: @Alex Mamo i add the code of the model class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a new instance of your adapter class and you pass a `List<PostModel>` objects to its constructor, it means that you want to create a view for each and every object that exists within that location. Seeing your screenshot, I can tell you for sure that under the "posts" node, there are no objects of type "PostModel", there are only String objects. To solve this, when you add data, make sure to have a schema similar to this:

```
Firebase-root
  |
  --- posts
       |
       --- postId
       |    |
       |    --- name: "Nice Image"
       |    |
       |    --- imgUrl: "https://..."
       |
       --- postId
            |
            --- name: "Very Nice Image"
            |
            --- imgUrl: "https://..."
```

Now, under the "posts" node you can see two "PostModel" objects. Now, you can attach a listener on this node, get the data as a `List<PostModel>`, pass this list to the adapter and the problem should be solved.

Comment: thanks for the reply, i will try this and if it works i will mark your reply as the answer.

Comment: Great, give it a try and tell me if it works ;)

Comment: I try everything I rewrite all the project from the beginning and is not working again, I can't see any post on the homepage. I will not continue working on this project. I will update the code on the question to see how the code looks like right now, and if you see where is the problem drop a new reply or edit the current. Let me know if you can help me or not to know if will continue the project or not

Comment: @GeorgeSepetadelis Please edit the question and add all the code that you are using now, including all changes.

Comment: i update the code on the question and also i add the template when i use for every new item on the recycler view. if you want any other code part of my project, drop a comment. (btw thanks for the patience and the help)

Comment: Does this line `Log.d("GGGGGGGGG","Value is: " + value);` print something in the logcat? Besides that, Please edit your question again and add your new database structure to see if it is exactly as in my answer.

Comment: Yes, is print the data correctly and yes I have the structure exactly as in your answer.

Comment: Add it to your question, to see it more clear.

Comment: okay i add the result of this part of code in the start of the question

Comment: I was asking about the new database schema. So both logs from the result belong to the existing users from the database, right?

Comment: Right, the new schema is 100% exactly as in your reply.

Comment: I cannot see it. Let me also take a look at it. Add a new screenshot of it.

Comment: Have you tried to add this line `postList = new ArrayList<>();` before this line `if (postList != null){...`?

Comment: yes i fix that with this, but now i can't load the image iside imageview from the url :-(

Comment: Good to hear that you fixed that :) The fact that you are getting another error, sounds as a new issue which basically should be considered another question that cannot be answered in a comment. It's beyond the scope of this question. As a personal guess, I think that is something related to Glide, but in order to follow the rules of this community, please post a new question using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I and other Firebase developers can help you.

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
postList.add(post);
//then
if (recyclerAdapter != null){
     recyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

You are adding an item to the list, but you are not notifying the adapter that an item has been added